# can shell themes be used with gnome fallback mode?

Tags: gnome

I was wondering what truly "gnome fallback" means in ubuntu? I am using gnome classic, which is lovely, but I wanna install some new themes. Do these themes only work with gnome 3? Do I have to get gnome 3 and then get themes activated in the advanced settings?

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

A desktop theme is broken into several components: window decorations, cursor theme, icon theme, GTK theme and the shell theme.

A shell theme doesn't do anything in a "Classic" environment as Gnome Shell isn't running, but you can still use the same window decoration and GTK theme settings.

I suggest you install `gnome-tweak-tool` and have a play around with the theme settings.